# Resizing D3.js and TechanJS chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, resize, line

I'm using D3.js and TechanJS to construct a market depth chart for several assets and am having issues getting the chart to resize when `window.onresize` fires.  I can neither get the axes nor the plots to resize whatsoever, although they do correctly size on initial drawing.

The problem I'm having is that the example code I have for resizing plots uses built-in TechanJS plots, which do not include an option for line plots.  The closest I can find is volume, which isn't exactly correct...  So instead I'm plotting the bids and asks as lines and do not know how to a) define them so as to me accessible by variable name and/or b) updated using `.call`

Here's how I'm plotting the axis to be resized and the bids and asks:

```
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).scale(d3.scaleLinear().domain(xPrice).range([0, dim.width-dim.margin.left-dim.margin.right]));

  ...

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis bottom");

  ...

  svg.append("path")
    .datum(bids)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("class", "bids")
    .attr("id", "bids")
    .attr("d", line);

  svg.append("path")
    .datum(asks)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("class", "asks")
    .attr("id", "asks")
    .attr("d", line);
```

And here's the `resize` function(s):

```
depthchart.resize = function(selection) {
  selection.call(resize).call(draw);
};

function resize(selection) {
  dim.width = selection.node().clientWidth;
  dim.height = selection.node().clientHeight;
  dim.plot.width = dim.width - dim.margin.left - dim.margin.right;
  dim.plot.height = dim.height - dim.margin.top - dim.margin.bottom;

  var xRange = [0, dim.plot.width],
      yRange = [dim.plot.height, 0],
      yTicks = Math.min(30, Math.round(dim.height/15)),
      xTicks = Math.min(20, Math.round(dim.width/100));

  x.range(xRange);
  xAxis.ticks(xTicks);
  y.range(yRange);
  yAxis.ticks(yTicks);
  priceAnnotation.translate([0, yRange[0]]);
  depthCrosshair.verticalWireRange([0, dim.plot.height]);

  selection.select("svg")
    .attr("width", dim.width);

  selection.selectAll("defs #depthClip > rect")
    .attr("width", dim.plot.width)
    .attr("height", dim.plot.height);

  selection.select("g.x.axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + dim.plot.height + ")");

  selection.selectAll("defs .plotClip > rect")
    .attr("width", dim.plot.width)
    .attr("height", dim.plot.height);
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: Full code can be seen at github.com/sneurlax/bpoch/tree/master/www/info with the code in question at github.com/sneurlax/bpoch/blob/master/www/info/js/ … An example can be seen at bpoch.info/btc

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but you might want to look at d3fc (https://d3fc.io), it has full support for resizing of charts and also has a number of financial features. If you need a hand using it, give me a shout.

Comment: d3fc looks great and BitFlux seems like exactly what I need... but adding Poloniex's api to d3fc-financial-feed could cause headaches :) I've started work at http://github.com/sneurlax/d3fc-financial-feed/tree/poloniex and http://github.com/sneurlax/BitFlux/tree/poloniex